# Web extension CSS overrides by webpage CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a chrome extension using https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react.
I have used the Tailwind CSS for all the component in the extension. Though the tailwind css is working in some pages, it's not working as expected on some other pages because of the extension css is get overrides by webpage css.

How to fix that the overriding issue, and also the on some webpages, the actual styling of that particular webpage is gone due to my extension installed.

I tried the actual css by configuring the css file in `manifest.js` file and also I tried the code for injecting CSS `chrome.scripting.injectCSS()`

Since it is not working as expected

Is there anyother way to fix this issue ? .. Please let me know

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So just to be clear, your extension adds elements directly into the page? Then you should probably look into using Shadow DOM for that, because that offers "encapsulation" from the rest of the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM